# constructor call or function-style cast in C++

Tags: c++

If I have the following c++ code:

```
class foo{
public:
    explicit foo(int i){};
};
void f(const foo &o){
}
```

And then I call

```
f(foo(1));
```

Is `foo(1)` constructor call or function-style cast?

Comment: Can't you only call constructors that way when declaring variables?

Comment: @Inerdial: not sure I understand you. Can you elaborate a bit? Thanks.

Comment: @Inerdial: No, you can call constructors like that too.

Comment: @QiangLi: I was asking if it's at all possible to call constructors without `new` as an expression, not as a variable declaration statement. (That said it's more of a vague guess which is why it's a comment not an answer.)

Comment: @Inerdial: it tends to get a bit vague when java/pythonists start guessing about C++ language features. Please post helpful comments _when_ you're pretty certain you're contributing.

Answer (score 4):

They are the same thing.

Comment: you mean I can consider them as either case?

Comment: LOL at `<!--------->` (I _had to_ see how you managed that) +1

Comment: @sehe: sorry about my English. What did you imply?

Comment: @QiangLi `:` that was at @OliCarlesworth :)

Comment: (Edit the answer to see what it means... answers need to be padded to a certain length, so Oli used a HTML comment to do it. This is going in my bag of tricks)

Answer (score 4):

It's a function-style cast that results in a constructor call, so both.

Comment: I thought only one is suffice. Then making a temporary copy to feed into the function is the next step thing. my question is only worrying about the code `foo(1)` part.

Answer (score 4):

> **5.2.3 Explicit type conversion (functional notation)**
>
> 1 A *simple-type-specifier* (7.1.6.2) or *typename-specifier* (14.6)
>   followed by a parenthesized *expression-list* constructs a value of
>   the specified type given the expression list. If the expression list
>   is a single expression, the **type conversion expression is equivalent
>   (in definedness, and if defined in meaning) to the corresponding cast
>   expression** (5.4). ...

Your code creates a temporary, using the constructor you have with the argument's value 1, and binds it to a const reference. The temporary's lifetime ends at the end of the statement where it was created.